# DataFrame assign inside function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, assign

I have a question regarding the df assign function. When using this function i must input the column name without apostrophes. Why is this and can i circumvent it? See example below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Grade'])
df['Grade'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

df_temp = df.assign(Grade='Total')

def dummy(df, _g):
# if I write grade here then I get the expected result
    return df.assign(_g='Total')

# here I want grade to be assigned to total but it creats a new variable called _g
df_temp = dummy(df, 'Grade')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def dummy(df, _g):
    return df.assign(**{_g: 'Total'})
```

Comment: Thanks nice solution. Can you explain why this is working?

Comment: @marcus I suggest googling "python keyword arguments" and "kwargs" and spending some time thoroughly understanding the concepts.